# Accessing Actual Objects with ResultSet Hit objects returned from index search on Djapian

Tags: django, object, indexing, return, resultset

I want to be able to have an actual list of objects returned when I query, instead of a ResultSet with Hit objects.

Example:

```
indexer.search(word).prefetch()
```

this would return a ResultSet object with matching hits, but I would like to have access to the objects themselves. Similar to what:

```
model.objects.filter(name__icontains=word)
```

would return.
the reason I don't just use the second option is that I cannot search cross-objects of different models, which can be done with indexing.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The object is returned afterall. It can be accessed with:

```
results = indexer.search(word).prefetch()
for hit in results:
    print hit.instance.model_attribute
```

where `model_attribute` would be an existing variable of the object returned

I believe class functions can be called upon as well in the model_attribute spot, (with bracket added in the end)

but note that when searching cross-models, the '`model_attribute`' may or may not exist for different models. So that may lead to errors.

I wish djapian had more documentation on this, as I couldn't find it at all